# jquery works only after page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, slideshow

I am using a responsive slider and many other scripts on my website. All scripts are working fine except slider's script. Slider's script only works when i refresh my page. I am failed to find a solution of this problem.
Here is the jquery code of slider:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#demo1').skdslider({delay:5000, animationSpeed: 2000,showNextPrev:true,showPlayButton:true,autoSlide:true,animationType:'fading'});
        jQuery('#demo2').skdslider({delay:5000, animationSpeed: 1000,showNextPrev:true,showPlayButton:false,autoSlide:true,animationType:'sliding'});
        jQuery('#demo3').skdslider({delay:5000, animationSpeed: 2000,showNextPrev:true,showPlayButton:true,autoSlide:true,animationType:'fading'});

        jQuery('#responsive').change(function(){
          $('#responsive_wrapper').width(jQuery(this).val());
          $(window).trigger('resize');
        });

    });
</script>
```

Jquery library is added in  section. and for slider code i tried different locations like in head section, body section and after body close tag also. Any help is appreciated...

Comment: You need to add `jQuery` **before** your slider script both right before the `</body>` tag.

Comment: i aggree with @D4V1D and would also like to ask why you always use jQuery and then use the $ instead. If you used jQuery because you have mootools or something else that blocks the $ sign as a function then you should either locally repurpous the $ to be used for jQuery or only use jQuery instead of the $

Comment: #d4v1d  i have already tried it

Comment: @AshishGarg: I mean to include `jQuery` once, right before your slideshow script, right before the `</body>` tag. This is where your put all your `JS` files, included in order if needed.

Comment: @D4V1D actually since his code is wrapped inside the ready function, it doesn't care if jquery script loading is done after or before.

Comment: @Masiorama: `it doesn't care if jquery is called right after or right before`... the `</body>` tag?

Comment: @ITroubs i don't have enough knowledge of jquery. You mean to say i should replace my $ sign with 'jquery' ??

Comment: actually you only have to replace it if you want to use mootools and jquery at the same time. if you only use jquery then it even would look nicer if you would replace `jQuery` with `$`

Comment: also please give us the whole html not only the little bit that you gave us

Comment: @D4V1D I was referring to after/before his custom code.

Comment: @Masiorama: fair enough. But including `jQuery` right before the `</body>` tag has nothing to do to whether his script will work but mostly so that the loading of page is not interrupted by the `JS` being loaded. Whether his script will work has to do with the order of the files included (e.g. `jQuery` **before** his slider library).

Comment: @ITroubs i am facing this issue on my site http://ludhianaweds.com index page. Slider only appears when i reload my page once.

Comment: @AshishGarg: you have a JS error in the console: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function in ludhianaweds.com/script1.js:1`

Comment: @D4V1D sure, I was simply stressing something that seemed not clear (at least to me) from your previous statement.

Comment: @D4V1D how should i know about the exact error. in script1 there is only scripts of social media and google analytics

Comment: So you have also a problem with GA script inclusion.
@Masiorama: no worries then :)

Comment: replace jquery to $ and can you show index page source code?

Comment: @rish very huge amount of code. But the issue is only in this code. You may see by 'show source code' option for the site http://ludhianaweds.com.

Comment: check console on developer tools if any errors occured

Comment: @OliSoproniB. Checked and solved all the errors...still slider is not loading in first attempt..

Comment: can you create fiddle or demo for us